# laravel store data from postman

Tags: php, laravel, postman, send

I want to use postman to store a new user in my database but it doesn't work.

My controller code:

```
public function store()
{  
    dd($request);
    $newuser = new User;
    $newuser -> fullname = request('fullname');
    $newuser -> email = request('email');
    $newuser -> password = request('password');
    $newuser -> username = request('username');
    $newuser -> status = 1;
    $newuser -> role_id = 1;
    $newuser -> save();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

My api route:

```
Route::post('users/store' , 'UsersController@store');
```

My url that is used in post man:

```
domain/api/user/store
```

fullname , email, usename and password should send with postman to store!
any one has solution for this?

Comment: Use `Request $request` in `store()` function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change**

```
public function store()
```

**To**

```
public function store(Request $request)
```

and don't forget to import the `Request` facade at the top (If you don't already have it):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

See this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests)!

Comment: @NasserAliKarimi You can access the data as you would access from a normal object. Just do `$request->field_name`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel `Input` facade.

```
$newuser->fullname = Input::get('fullname');
```